Reference Request: Picard Group of Plane Cover Ramified at a Given Curve
I am currently working in the following setting: Let $p(x_0,x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ define a plane curve $C = V(p)$ of even degree $2d$, and let $X = \text{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[y,x_0,x_1,x_2]/(y^d- p)) \subseteq \mathbb{P}(2,1,1,1)$ be the $d$-fold cover of the plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ ramified at $C$.
My goal is to understand the Picard group of $X$. If $d = 2$, then $X$ is a del Pezzo surface and it is known that $\text{Pic}(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^8$.
My search so far has produced this paper (+ its references) from 1985 that makes some calculations on the Picard group of $X$, (Theorem 7.1. and Theorem 7.3.). However, this is in a more general setting (complete intersections), and I would be interested in something more explicit for my specific setting (hypersurfaces of the type described above).
Do you know something that might be helpful?
Best,
Clemens
